# How to describe a system

Tags: business-analyst, interview

I am new to this community and please go easy on me.

I have been doing C# dev for like 10 years and recently I am considering a Business Analyst (BA) position. When I applied for the role, the manager asked me to do some little homework and I hope I can get some advice from you.

The preparation for the interview was to describe an existing cinema online booking system in 200 words.

What got me was the number of words as 200 words isnt much and it makes thing tricky. I want to get some advice on if there is any specific BA way to describe a system. How would you describe a system in 200 words? would you do that in point form?

Update:

I realised I didn't make my question very clear. I was asked to describe a particular cinema movie booking system, so it is not any booking system. I just didn't want to name the particular cinema in my question.

I can even try to explain my approach and hope everyone can tell me if this is a BA way to doing it.

1. Evaluated the booking system and understood its booking process
2. Drew up a UML Sequence diagram to note down the end-to-end booking steps
3. Translating the booking process from diagram into words

Hope this is something acceptable for most

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework question and because it has nothing to do with PjM.

Comment: In my defence, this is more of an interview question. I used the word homework, but it isn't a homework for study. It's a valid work related question

Comment: @DannySchoemann Homework questions aren't inherently off-topic, but they should certainly be useful questions that fit PMSE norms.

Comment: @Jack Your question *as phrased* is off-topic, but there's a nugget in there that's project-related if you decide to edit your question. Really, what you're after is the product's **features or specifications**, which I suppose you can describe as verbosely or as parsimoniously as you like to fit the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to read the manager's mind; my guess is that he is looking to see if you can communicate efficiently.

I would do the following:

1. Identify the problem that the "cinema online booking system" is supposed to solve.
2. Identify the features that the "cinema online booking system" must have to solve the identified problem.  You can probably limit this to 5 or 10 due to the word limit in place.
3. Prioritize the list of features identified in step 2.
4. Write a 200 word [product vision statement](https://www.scrumalliance.org/community/articles/2009/january/the-product-vision) for the system using the information gathered in steps 1-3 above.

Comment: Thanks @drneel. Sorry I realised I didn't make my question clear enough, which I already updated in my question. I think what you said is inline with my thinking, so I may give it a shot and see how it goes